# VBA: Dynamic range in Excel - finding the last column with relevant data

Tags: excel, vba

I have different sheets in a workbook from which I want to copy data. I could write out the range manually for each sheet because the size of it shouldn't change that often. However, I'd really like it to be more elegant and loop through it. Problem is, the data on each sheet can be slightly different and now I don't know how to find the last column.

On the different sheets, the first column and row are always empty, then the data I want (4+ columns of it) follows. There are three variants of this (so far):

1. Just the range with the data I need. Simple enough

   lCol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
2. Sometimes, however, there is an empty column to the right of the data I want, followed by a column with irrelevant data: [image: Data structure2]

If that was the only case, I'd adjust my code to the following:

```
lCol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).End(xlToLeft).Column
If lCol = 2 Then
    lCol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End If
```

3. Unfortunately, I also have sheets that have yet some more (irrelevant) data to the right of it:

[image: Data structure3]

I don't know how to address this. Basically I need code that tells Excel to pick the biggest continuous range, that is the range that has no empty columns

edit: I don't know if it helps, but the data I'm looking for in each sheet has a border around it (it's formatted as a table)

Comment: Is an actual table from excel or just fromated to look like a table?

Comment: Formatted to look like a table

Comment: Well I suppose that you could do `Range("B2").End(xlToRight).Column` that would give you the last column of that range, if always starts like this.

Comment: God I'm dumb...

Thank you for the help!